# Implementing a variable from public class to public in java

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I had a queue implemented as linked list. I want to sort this queue from another class. Both classes are in the same package. My sorted list is on the public class and I want to put it in the public so I can make a GUI. I think I'm missing something and I don't know what it is. Can someone help me.

This is my full code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.*;

public class Search extends JFrame {

    private JLabel      lblSearch;
    private JTextField  txtSearch;
    private JButton     btnSort, btnborrow, btnreturn, btnsearch;
    public JList        listbooks, returnbooks;
    public Object[]     books;
    private ListModel[] listmodel;

    private LinkedList          ll  = new LinkedList(); {
        ll.add("The Fault In Our Stars");
        ll.add("Solid Mensuration");
        ll.add("Analytic Geometry");
        ll.add("Engineering Mechanics");
        ll.add("Perks Of Being A Wallflower");
        ll.add("Reckless");
        ll.add("Paper Towns");
        ll.add("Stewart's Algebra And Trigonometry");
        ll.add("The Lost Hero");
        ll.add("The Son Of Neptune");
        ll.add("Harry Potter And The Sorcerer's Stone");
        ll.add("Paper Towns");
        ll.add("Looking For Alaska");
        ll.add("Principles Of Taxation");
        ll.add("Contemporary Physics");
        ll.add("The House Of Hades");
        ll.add("The Last Olympian");
        ll.add("An Imperial Affliction");
        ll.add("The Daily Bread");
        ll.add("Looking For Alaska");
        ll.add("The Lightning Thief");
        ll.add("Sociology Focus On The Philippines");
        ll.add("The Red Pyramid");
        ll.add("Demigod Diaries");
        ll.add("The Battle Of The Labyrinth");
        ll.add("Webster's Dictionary");
        ll.add("Strength Of Materials");
        ll.add("Discrete Mathematics");
        ll.add("The Serpent's Shadow");
        ll.add("Twilight");
        ll.add("Breaking Dawn");
        ll.add("Eclipse");
        ll.add("Diary Of A Wimpy Kid");
        ll.add("Electronic Devices And Circuit Theory");
        ll.add("The Princess And The Frog");
        ll.add("Fifty Shades Of Grey");
        ll.add("The Mark Of Athena");
        ll.add("The Throne Of Fire");
        ll.add("Fifty Shades Of Grey");
        ll.add("Divergent");
        ll.add("Data Structures And Algorithms");
        ll.add("Introduction To Operating System");
        ll.add("Integral Calculus");
        ll.add("Life And Works Of Rizal");
        ll.add("The Sea Of Monsters");
        ll.add("Insurgent");
        ll.add("Holy Bible");
    }

    public Search() {

        super("TIPQC-Library: SEARCH");
        setLayout(null);
        getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLACK);

        txtSearch = new JTextField(30);
        txtSearch.setBounds(80, 100, 240, 30);
        add(txtSearch);

        btnsearch = new JButton("Search");
        btnsearch.setBounds(330, 100, 90, 28);
        add(btnsearch);

        DefaultListModel<Object> model = new DefaultListModel<Object>();
        for (Object element : ll)
            model.addElement(element);

        listbooks = new JList(model);
        listbooks.setBounds(80, 180, 350, 100);
        listbooks.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
        listbooks.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        listbooks.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        add(listbooks);

        JScrollPane tscroll = new JScrollPane(listbooks);
        tscroll.setBorder(null);
        tscroll.setBounds(80, 180, 350, 100);
        tscroll.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
        tscroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        add(tscroll);

        btnSort = new JButton("Sort");
        btnSort.setBounds(90, 300, 80, 25);
        add(btnSort);

        btnreturn = new JButton("Return");
        btnreturn.setBounds(220, 300, 80, 25);
        add(btnreturn);

        btnborrow = new JButton("Borrow");
        btnborrow.setBounds(340, 300, 80, 25);
        add(btnborrow);

        returnbooks = new JList();
        returnbooks.setBounds(80, 380, 350, 100);
        returnbooks.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
        returnbooks.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        returnbooks.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        add(returnbooks);

        ActionListener listener = new ButtonListener();
        btnborrow.addActionListener(listener);
        btnSort.addActionListener(listener);

    }

    public class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            Object source = e.getSource();
            if (source == btnborrow)
            {
                Object removed;
                DefaultListModel model = (DefaultListModel) listbooks.getModel();
                int selectedIndex = listbooks.getSelectedIndex();
                if (selectedIndex != -1) {
                    removed = model.remove(selectedIndex);
                }
            }

            if (source == btnSort) {

                Collections.sort(ll);

                ListIterator liter = ll.listIterator();
                Collections.sort(ll);
                liter = ll.listIterator();
                while (liter.hasNext())
                    System.out.println(liter.next());
            }

        }

    }

    public void run() {

        setSize(500, 500);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setResizable(false);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Search log = new Search();
        log.run();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your problem a little bit more. Doesn't the sorting work?

Comment: There is a lot of unnecessary code here. I would recommend revising the question so that it becomes shorter and clearer exactly what it is you're asking.

Comment: im asking is i don't know how to make the sort display in gui style it only show in output bar my prof. said it must be in gui. sorry my english is bad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean, like showing the sorted list in the GUI?

```
                Collections.sort(ll);

                ListIterator liter = ll.listIterator();
                Collections.sort(ll);
                liter = ll.listIterator();

                DefaultListModel model = (DefaultListModel) listbooks.getModel();
                model.clear();
                for (Object element : ll)
                    model.addElement(element);
                //while (liter.hasNext())
                //  System.out.println(liter.next());
```

Comment: can i ask what is this type of sorting algo??

Comment: I think it's an enhanced version of quicksort